# property value have changed but not effected

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
<script>

           var Faizan = {
               isSharp: true,
               use: function(){
                 return this.isSharp = "Dangerous"//!this.isSharp;
               }
           };
           console.log(Faizan.use());
           console.log( !Faizan.isSharp, "Verify the value of isSharp has been changed." );
       </script>
```

Output of the above script is
1.Dangerous
**2.False**
1st output is very sample as i expected it but second output is surprisingly false Why?
when *isSharp* is change to *Dangerous* then Why *!Faizan.isSharp* Returning False?? isSharp value have changed

Comment: Because `!` is the logical NOT operator, which first converts `Faizan.isSharp` to a boolean value - `ToBoolean("Dangerous") === true`, and then negates it - so `!Faizan.isSharp` === `!ToBoolean("Dangerous")` === `!true` === `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sacho said "!" is the logical NOT operator, so:

```
  p   |  !p
-------------
true  | false 
false | true
```

In JavaScript non-empty string will evaluate to true if tested, see example below:

```
var simpleText = "This is simple text";
if (simpleText) {
  console.log("The value is truthy");
} else {
  console.log("The value is falsy");
}
// => The value is truthy
```

And empty string will evalute to false:

```
var emptyText = "";
if (emptyText) {
  console.log("The value is truthy");
} else {
  console.log("The value is falsy");
} 
// => The value is falsy
```

You can read more about that here: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

TL;DR

Your statement !Faizan.isSharp is equal to !true which is equal to false.